# How to roll up the plane into cylinder?

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

There is a set of points (in cartesian coordinates), that all lie on the plane. The problem is in rolling up the plane into cylinder in selected direction.

I tried transformation of the coordinates into cylindrical coordinate system.
First I defined the value of radius (basing on some not related considerations). Then, I got following coordinates in cylindrical system:

$$\begin{Bmatrix}
\rho_i= \sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2} \\
\varphi_i= atan(y_i/x_i) \\
z_i=z_i \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

and substituted $\rho_i$ by the value of calculated radius and performed transformation back to cartesian coordinates:
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
x_i = \rho_icos\varphi_i \\
y_i = \rho_isin\varphi_i \\
z_i=z_i \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

But as expected, it gave only half-cylinder.
Unfortunately, I am very weak in math, so, I suppose, that there is a simple solution for this problem, but I can not formulate it correctly.

Thanks in advance. MuKeP.

Comment: What do you mean with "rolling up the plane"? Notice that, if you see the plane as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it is not omeomorphic to a cylinder, hence you cannot find such coordinate system without losing some points of the cylinder

Comment: @JayTuma, I imply something like this: [link](http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap3/Chap3-9/cylind.gif). May be it is possible to define the law of transformation. It is not necessary to use exactly transformation to cylindrical coordinates. Some way to change coordinates along selected direction.

Comment: the immage refers only to a bounded portion of the plane, is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JayTuma, yes, you are right. I have found one more example. not exact, but something similar [link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RollingUpASheetOfGraphene/).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the unit vector $\mathbf{u}$ is the direction in which one wishes to roll up the plane into a cylinder. If we let the radius of the cylinder $r=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ then the transformation is essentially a rotation of the plane by an angle $\phi$ satisfying $\cos\phi=\mathbf{u}\cdot(1,0)$. Let $\mathbf{v}$ denote the unit vector in the direction of the rotated $y$-axis orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$. The rotated axes $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ are represented by the dotted lines in the diagram.
[image: plane mapped to cylinder]

Construct a cylinder about the $x^\prime$ axis with radius $r=\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Then a point $(x,y)$ will be transformed to a point $(a,b)$ in the rotated system where, using the standard rotation formulas,

\begin{eqnarray}
a&=&\phantom{-}x\cos\phi-y\sin\phi\\
b&=&-x\sin\phi+y\sin\phi
\end{eqnarray}
In the cylindrical coordinates, $r=a,\,\theta=b$. So the transformation is

\begin{eqnarray}
r&=&\phantom{-}x\cos\phi-y\sin\phi\\
\theta&=&-x\sin\phi+y\sin\phi
\end{eqnarray}

It is a many-to-one transformation since the entire plane is wrapped around the cylinder. If a cylinder with a radius different from $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is desired, then $\theta$ must be scaled accordingly.